# how to get valid fb access_token using php curl?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a project which require an access token of the user using curl. 
The user will enter his username and password. he will be logged in to facebook using curl. The login part works. I also gets a token that has the pipline in it like: xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, but i want an access token to post to the logged in user wall.

The code that i am using is:

```
// your facebook credentials
$username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";

// access to facebook home page (to get the cookies)
$curl = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.facebook.com" );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd () . '/cookies_facebook.cookie' );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)" );
$curlData = curl_exec ( $curl );
curl_close ( $curl );

// do get some parameters for login to facebook
$charsetTest = substr ( $curlData, strpos ( $curlData, "name=\"charset_test\"" ) );
$charsetTest = substr ( $charsetTest, strpos ( $charsetTest, "value=" ) + 7 );
$charsetTest = substr ( $charsetTest, 0, strpos ( $charsetTest, "\"" ) );

$locale = substr ( $curlData, strpos ( $curlData, "name=\"locale\"" ) );
$locale = substr ( $locale, strpos ( $locale, "value=" ) + 7 );
$locale = substr ( $locale, 0, strpos ( $locale, "\"" ) );

$lsd = substr ( $curlData, strpos ( $curlData, "name=\"locale\"" ) );
$lsd = substr ( $lsd, strpos ( $lsd, "value=" ) + 7 );
$lsd = substr ( $lsd, 0, strpos ( $lsd, "\"" ) );

// do login to facebook
$curl = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1" );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "charset_test=" . $charsetTest . "&locale=" . $locale . "&non_com_login=&email=" . $username . "&pass=" . $password . "&charset_test=" . $charsetTest . "&lsd=" . $lsd );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd () . '/cookies_facebook.cookie' );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd () . '/cookies_facebook.cookie' );
curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)" );



$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
$postString = "client_id=XXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&type=client_cred";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
$access_token = str_replace( "access_token=", "", curl_exec($curl) );

echo $access_token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use curl? You can't use PHPSDK? Its more easy...

However i think you miss pase permissions parameters.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/

Answer (score 0):

the SDK PHP library (you can find an updated version [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)) uses cURL too. Are we, by any chance, reinventing the wheel?

Comment: thanks for the answers. actually i will save the username and password in the db and then use them to get the access token of the user

Comment: that's bad practice... You store the access token, and that's even too much to my modest opinion. I'd never give my login credentials to anyone

Comment: you are right, but the app will be self hosted on the person's website site. And thats the requirement.

Comment: the app will post on user behalf using a cron job.

Comment: for that purpose, if you need it for just one person, you could add them as admins/developers of the app. The access token of the app's developers/admins lasts forever. For my own cron jobs I use my own app and my own access tokens (page access tokens included). Because the app is mine, the tokens never expire. Just an idea.